# First Value of dictionary not getting assigned to combobox in C#

Tags: c#

I am using Dictionary collection in C#. I want to display first value of dictionary
to combo box so that combo box by default shows first value.but instead of the first value null value get assigned.
I tried following code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> sampleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
sampleDictionary.add("ABC","XYZ");
sampleDictionary.add("JKL","PQR");

comboBox.SelectedValue=sampleDictionary.Values.First();
```

Comment: Might be a typo, but you have two dots after comboBox. Of course you need just one...

Comment: @selmaohneh corrected the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You should add the values of the dictionary to your comboBox as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, string> sampleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
comboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(sampleDictionary, null);
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Then, you could try: `comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;`